# How to make a DataReader for global use

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in my SQL Connect class.

```
public class SqlConnect
{
    public string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection con;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter sda;
    private DataTable dt;
    private SqlDataReader sdr;

    public SqlConnect()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
    }
    public void SqlQuery(string queryTxt)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryTxt, con);
    }
    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;

    }
    public void NonQueryEx()
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    public void Reader()
    {           
       sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(sdr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++) ;

        }
        return;
    }
```

Now, in my button I have this code. I'm having error saying cannot convert from Void to Object.

```
        con = new SqlConnect();
        con.SqlQuery("Select Department from Salary");
        cboDept.Items.Add(con.Reader());
```

My question is how can I make this run? when I use the public **datatable QueryEx** I can only get the column name appear on the combobox (just the Column name). I'm searching here but I cant find any solution. How to make this code run?

Comment: Just use your QueryEx with _cboDept.DataSource = con.QueryEx():_

Comment: But let me suggest you that these classes that should encapsulate the details of data access code are just an infinite source of errors. If you want to learn the correct way to do this then look at some ORM tool like Dapper or Entity Framework.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you for that, I tried it  and shows the exact number of the items from database. However the items showing "System.Data.DataRowView". Anything to add?
Is that possible to use the datareader as well? I want it that  way.

On your guess, I did not reach that yet. just want to finish this first.

Comment: Thank you steve. I added this code  cboDept.DisplayMember = "Department"; and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Also, it's generally a bad practice to try to and manage your connection like this as it can potentially lead to leaked connections. In a WinForms environment, it's not as dangerous as it is in a web environment, but it is something to be cognizant of, especially if you have lots of WinForms clients talking to the same database. If you have an exception that is thrown in your `NonQueryEx` method from your code above and caught at a higher level, your `SqlConnection` will be left open.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The way you want to make your database calls is to wrap your construction of your `SqlConnection` object in a `using` block:

Example:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you're wanting to use an abstraction layer to save yourself from typing, wrap your call within a `using` block within that layer. This is the #1 mistake that I see with ADO.Net code at new clients (in other words, this is an incredibly common mistake and don't let this criticism discourage you). ADO.Net manages connections behind the scenes. Opening and closing a connection does not actually terminate a connection to a database, it releases it to the pool so the next call to .Open or .Close can reuse that same connection. Holding onto it for any longer than necessary means that new connections may need to be created. Likewise, there is no guarantee when your SqlConnect() instances will be cleaned up by .Net, so if you have a repeated exception that is caught at a higher level, this can result in multiple connections waiting to be released until your SqlConnect class is garbage collected.